# Having trouble connecting a project to a Postgresql database (Is the server running locally and accepting connections?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am trying to connect a ruby on rails project to have a postgresql database so I can deploy on heroku when I am finished. I have tried to dig for the answer myself and have very limited knowledge on postgresql and how to debug so please be very specific if you have any ideas on what I could do to fix this.

Background information:
I have done one project with this with no issues but this is a new project and I had to uninstall and reinstall postgresql because of another error I now have postgresql 12 I believe.

I am just starting a new project and when running `$rake db:create` I am getting the following error:

```
Database 'gachamons_backend_development' already exists
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
Couldn't create 'gachamons_backend_test' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/mnt/c/users/adam/desktop/flatiron/gachamons-backend/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/users/adam/desktop/flatiron/gachamons-backend/bin/spring:10:in `require'
/mnt/c/users/adam/desktop/flatiron/gachamons-backend/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/mnt/c/users/adam/desktop/flatiron/gachamons-backend/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
/mnt/c/users/adam/desktop/flatiron/gachamons-backend/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/mnt/c/users/adam/desktop/flatiron/gachamons-backend/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/users/adam/desktop/flatiron/gachamons-backend/bin/spring:10:in `require'
/mnt/c/users/adam/desktop/flatiron/gachamons-backend/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/mnt/c/users/adam/desktop/flatiron/gachamons-backend/bin/spring:7:in `tap'
/mnt/c/users/adam/desktop/flatiron/gachamons-backend/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When I try to see if the server is down using `$service postgresql status` :

```
12/main (port 5432): down
```

`$psql` :

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I saw from another post to run `$dpkg -l | grep postgres` which yields this output which I don't understand how to debug:

```
ii  postgresql                        12+214                             all          object-relational SQL database (supported version)
ii  postgresql-12                     12.2-4                             amd64        object-relational SQL database, version 12 server
ii  postgresql-client-12              12.2-4                             amd64        front-end programs for PostgreSQL 12
ii  postgresql-client-common          214                                all          manager for multiple PostgreSQL client versions
ii  postgresql-common                 214                                all          PostgreSQL database-cluster manager
ii  postgresql-contrib                12+214                             all          additional facilities for PostgreSQL (supported version)
```

Then I ran `$pg_lsclusters` :

`12  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log`

Finally `$sudo service postgresql restart`

```
* Restarting PostgreSQL 12 database server           * Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/12/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log -s -o  -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf"  exited with status 1: 
2021-08-24 15:48:39.458 EDT [4148] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Ubuntu 12.2-4) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-8ubuntu1) 9.3.0, 64-bit
2021-08-24 15:48:39.460 EDT [4148] LOG:  could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Permission denied
2021-08-24 15:48:39.460 EDT [4148] HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
2021-08-24 15:48:39.460 EDT [4148] WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
2021-08-24 15:48:39.460 EDT [4148] FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
2021-08-24 15:48:39.461 EDT [4148] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

Edit to include database.yml :

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: gachamons_backend_development
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  user: postgres
  password: postgres

test:
  <<: *default
  database: gachamons_backend_test
  port: 5432
  user: postgres
  password: postgres

production:
  <<: *default
  url: <%= ENV['MY_APP_DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

These are all of the things I've tried to debug but I am not familiar enough to understand the meanings of the outputs. Any detailed explanations so I can understand for next time would be appreciated to get me from a to b. Thanks very much.

Comment: database.yml would be extremely helpful here.

Comment: @engineersmnky Thank you for the helpful response! I edited and added that info!

Comment: Your test environment has no host. This is likely the issue because it recognizes your development database and only fails for test.

Comment: @engineersmnky That worked I can't believe that was the problem after all that research! You are a life saver thank you! I am new to stack overflow, Is there a way to give you credit for an answer in a comment?

Comment: No comments are just comments however I don't know that I would really consider that an "answer" either. Glad it work for you but it is more of a simple oversight that I was able to point out. Good luck moving forward and feel free to stop back if you have any additional questions you cannot find answers to.

Answer (score 0):

From the above output, postgresql database is down.
In the postgresql configuration file (/etc/postgresql/12/main/postgresql.conf), enter:
listen_addresses='*'

Then restart postgresql.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Interestingly, My files are postgresql/13 instead of postgresql/12 not sure why or if that matters. I checked inside that config file and listen_addresses='*' was already included... :( Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: then there are 2 instances installed.
1. PostgreSQL 12
2. PostgreSQL 13

Try, stopping postgresql 13 and then issue the postgresql 12 restart, as they maybe running on same port 5432.

Answer (score 0):

user @engineersmnky pointed out the test environment in database.yml had no host, creating multiple errors when trying to create database.